# Getting Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, magento

I am getting this error in 3 spots in the function that I pasted below. There is more to this code, but I didn't think it was needed to get this thing figured out.

```
$count = count($collection);    
$i = 1 ; 
foreach ($collection as $product) 
{
    $j = 1 ;
    $productId = $product->getDiamondsearchId();
    $attributValueOptions = "[" ;
    $attributValueOptions .= "'".$productId."', "; 
    foreach($filterAttributeIds as $filterAttributeId){

        $attributValueCollection = Mage::getModel('diamondsearch/diamondsearchattributvalue')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribut_id',$filterAttributeId)->addFieldToFilter('diamondsearch_id',$productId)->getData();

        $attrbutValueId = $attributValueCollection[0]['attrbut_value_id'];
        //echo $attrbutValueId."<br>";
        $attributValueOptionCollection = Mage::getModel('diamondsearch/diamondsearchattributoptionvalue')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id',$attrbutValueId)->getData();
        if($j == 1 && $attributValueOptionCollection[0]['attribut_value'] == ""){

        break ;
        }
        if($j == 15){
            $attributValueOptions .= "'".$attributValueOptionCollection[0]['attribut_value']."'"; 
        }else{
            $attributValueOptions .= "'".$attributValueOptionCollection[0]['attribut_value']."', "; 
        }
        $j++;
    }
    if($count == $i ){
    $attributValueOptions .= "]";
    }else{
    $attributValueOptions .= "], ";
    }
    $i++;
    echo $attributValueOptions ;


}
```

Comment: Are you manually building a JSON array? Is that what the square brackets are for?

Comment: undefinedoffset = you're trying to use an array entry which doesn't exist. e.g. you should try `var_dump($attributValueOptionCollection)` or whatever and see what's really in there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cpjv1k8d/. This is the entire javascript being used. This code was done by someone else so I am unclear on his thought process.

Comment: http://american.fmwebd.com/diamondsearch -- This is what I am working on to give you the full picture.

Comment: I added a dump Marc, if you go to that link I provided, you will see the output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
$attributValueCollection = Mage::getModel('diamondsearch/diamondsearchattributvalue')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribut_id',$filterAttributeId)->addFieldToFilter('diamondsearch_id',$productId)->getData();
$attrbutValueId = $attributValueCollection[0]['attrbut_value_id'];
```

You're trying to get the first item of array, but this variable is empty. You should verify and then do the stuff you want, like this:

```
if(!empty(attributValueCollection)){
 $attrbutValueId = $attributValueCollection[0]['attrbut_value_id'];
```

Here's the complete gist:
https://gist.github.com/muriloazevedo/8dc5b11b17d1c4a3a518

But also is important to remember, if you trying to generate a json result, is better to use json_encode for that:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thank you Murilo. There was a couple of small errors in your code, but I was able to remedy those really quick. Sadly though, this extension still isn't functional. I am now thinking this extension might be a lost cause which is a shame.